# how to restrict view in angularjs application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to restrict user's to access /dashboard view and /add-item view or any other view in my angular js application.

this is my router

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('login');

        $stateProvider.
            state('app.dashboard', {
                url: '/dashboard',
                templateUrl: appHelper.viewsPath('dashboard/views/dashboard'),
                controller: 'DashBoardController as DashBordCtrl',
     }).

            // Add Item
            state('app.add-item', {
                url: '/add-item',
                templateUrl: appHelper.viewsPath('item/views/add-item'),
                controller: 'ItemController as ItemCtrl',
            })
        });
```

After login I am storing the token in my local storage. I want user to not access any view if token is not present.

this is my login controller

```
$scope.register = function(credentials){
       LoginService.post(credentials,function(success){
           $state.go('app.add-item');
          SessionService.set("token",success.accessToken);


             },function(error){
       FlashService.showError("Please Enter Valid Email Password");
        });
    }
    }
```

On 401 error i am redirecting to login page like this:

```
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
   // $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = '';
     delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($location, $q, SessionService, FlashService) {
        return {
            request: function (config) {
                 config.headers = config.headers || {};
                config.headers.Authorization = SessionService.get('token');
                return config;
            },
            responseError: function (response) {
                if (response.status === 401) {
                   SessionService.unset('token');
                    $location.path('/login');
                }
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        };
    });
});
```

But if I type /add-item in url, my add-item page is opening and then it suddenly close,because server return 401 ,and login page appear.I don't want to open any view if user is not login.

I am new in angularjs and i am confusing how to do this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If token is not present,You can save the user's location to take him back to the same page after he has logged-in.You can review following code in app.js:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){    

        $stateProvider.
            state('app.dashboard', {
                url: '/dashboard',
                templateUrl: appHelper.viewsPath('dashboard/views/dashboard'),
                controller: 'DashBoardController as DashBordCtrl',
     }).

            // Add Item
            state('app.add-item', {
                url: '/add-item',
                templateUrl: appHelper.viewsPath('item/views/add-item'),
                controller: 'ItemController as ItemCtrl',
            })
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('login');
        });
```

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('login') replace with  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('app/dashboard') in app.config.if it is  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('login') ,you have a token ,throw login page still.

```
 app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
       // $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = '';
         delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];

        $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($location, $q, SessionService, FlashService) {
            return {
                request: function (config) {
                     config.headers = config.headers || {};
                    config.headers.Authorization = SessionService.get('token');
                    return config;
                },
                responseError: function (response) {
                    if (response.status === 401) {
                       SessionService.unset('token');
                        $location.path('/login');
                    }
                    return $q.reject(response);
                }
     if (!SessionService.get('token');) {
                    /* You can save the user's location to take him back to                 the same page after he has logged-in */
                    $rootScope.savedLocation = $location.url();

                    $location.path('/login');
                }
            };
        });
    });
```

Comment: thanx for the reply , but my add-item page is still flash for a second when i write /add-item in url , and then login page open. My problem is i want user to be on login page if token is not present, watever be the url is..

Answer (score 0):

You should use **resolve** in your route configuration. Example:

```
state('app.add-item', {
            url: '/add-item',
            templateUrl: appHelper.viewsPath('item/views/add-item'),
            controller: 'ItemController as ItemCtrl',
            resolve: ['SomeService', function(SomeService) {
                return SomeService.getDataFromApi();
            }]
        })
```

Looking at this example, if SomeService returns 401, meaning an error, that route controller will never instantiate and therefor you cannot access the view. Your interceptor will still do his job, and redirect to login when 401 happens, but now it will happen smoothly and with no flash of the view.

This is a good way to do, and it will solve that problem of yours and also some others you might encounter later.

Comment: thanx for reply . I think it will work , but can i check the token in resolve,instead of 401 error .

Comment: The point is, you can only check if the token exist. You cannot check if the token is valid, that is the point. 
The check you want to do will only work for the first time users and possibly for the ones that manually logout on the last visit.

Comment: So do i have to make some service that will hit api and get data,whether the token is valid or not ?? and then inject it into every resolve part?

Comment: No, interceptor stays as is, you do not implement special call to see if token is valid. All you need to do now, is to set resolve blocks in your routes. So instead of calling the api from the specific controller, you will just call it like this, in the resolve, and then serve the data to the controller (read more about this in the uiRoutes docs if you do not understand it)